# Installing chocolatey in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, chocolatey

```
I am trying to installing chocolaty on windows 7 machine.
1. I open power shell terminal with admin 
2. Set-Execution policy to AllSigned
3.Then in copied the below code in powershell terminal
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072;
   iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

But I am getting the following error message as below
Exception setting "securityProtocol": "cannot convert value "3312" to type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolTypeValid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The Possible enumerations are "Sel3, Tls"

Comment: Chocolatey needs tls 1,2.  Try installing offline.  See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041438/2953889

Comment: I upgraded my powershell version from 2.0 to 5.1 then the chocolatey is installed in online mode only